How to validate a field from one schema using a field value from another schema inside the diffent shape?
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
 RecipientDetail: Yup.object().shape({
  EmployeeOfferAndCoverage: Yup.object().shape({
  MonthlyOfferCoverageGrp: Yup.object().shape({
    AllOfferCd: Yup.string(),
  }),
  MonthlyEmployeeRequiredContriGrp: Yup.object().shape({
    AllMonthAmt: Yup.number().when(
      'RecipientDetail.EmployeeOfferAndCoverage.MonthlyOfferCoverageGrp.AllOfferCd', 
      {
        is: (val) => val !== undefined && val !== null && val !== '',  // Check if 
   AllOfferCd has a value
        then: Yup.number()
          .max(3500, 'Amount cannot exceed 3500')
          .nullable(),  // Allow null if condition is not met
        otherwise: Yup.number().nullable(), // Allow null for other cases
       }
      ),
     }),
    }),
  }),
 });

I have get the value for this reference 'RecipientDetail.EmployeeOfferAndCoverage.MonthlyOfferCoverageGrp.AllOfferCd'is  undefined. I could not solve this issue

The issue here is that Yup's .when condition is limited to fields within the same shape level, so it can’t access deeply nested fields in another schema directly.
To work around this, you can use Yup's .test method, which allows for a custom validation function where you can access all values in the schema. Here’s how to modify your schema:

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  RecipientDetail: Yup.object().shape({
    EmployeeOfferAndCoverage: Yup.object().shape({
      MonthlyOfferCoverageGrp: Yup.object().shape({
        AllOfferCd: Yup.string(),
      }),
      MonthlyEmployeeRequiredContriGrp: Yup.object().shape({
        AllMonthAmt: Yup.number()
          .nullable()
          .test(
            'maxAmountIfOfferCdExists',
            'Amount cannot exceed 3500',
            function (value) {
              const { RecipientDetail } = this.parent.parent.parent; // Access the root object
              const AllOfferCd = RecipientDetail?.EmployeeOfferAndCoverage?.MonthlyOfferCoverageGrp?.AllOfferCd;
              
              if (AllOfferCd) {
                // Only validate max when AllOfferCd has a value
                return value === null || value <= 3500;
              }
              return true; // Otherwise, allow any value including null
            }
          ),
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

